# How to pass the table-valued parameters to stored procedure in mssql useing sequelize/sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I saw the [Github issue 9683](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9683), but I still confuse how to do that.

Can someone get me a specific example?

1. How to generate the table-valued parameters？
2. How to call stored procudure and pass the table-valued parameters？

Thanks  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking mssql npm package and look for the Table-Valued Parameter (TVP) section.
Here's the link;
https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql